How to attribute PnL to factors in a multi factor model
I have a multi factor model and I am trying to decompose PnL of a given portfolio into different factors. This theory makes sense.

But lets consider a portfolio of $n$ ($n$ is same as no of factors in our model) stocks from a particular country (lets say Japan). Assume that all the stocks have exposure to currency JPY.
The multifactor model includes Japan and JPY factors as 2 separate factors. Also assume that the portfolio is equi-weighted among all the stocks so $W$ is basically an identity matrix, $W=I$.
Now $X^TWX$ is effectively $X^TX$. $X$ would have two columns filled with 1 as the exposure of all stocks to factors JPY and Japan is going to be 1. But due to this $\text{det}(X) = 0$ and so $\text{det}(X^TX)=0$. So, $X^TWX$ is not invertible.
How is this solved in multi factor modelling for such cases?

Where is the quote / picture from? It would also be nicer if you recreated it in text in the question rather than using a screenshot which is less convenient for many people.

You can add a small penalty term which penalizes the L2 norm of factor returns. So instead of solving
$$
\min_f || r - Xf||_2^2
$$
you solve
$$
\min_f ||r-Xf||_2^2 + \lambda ||f||_2^2
$$
which has the solution (assuming unit weights)
$$
\hat{f} = (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^T r
$$
You can make $\lambda$ as small as you like, and $X^TX+\lambda I$ will always be invertible even when $X$ contains linearly dependent factors. The limit as $\lambda$ goes to zero is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of $X^TX$ i.e
$$
\hat{f} = (X^T X)^+ X^T r
$$
In the specific case you discussed, where every stock has unit exposure to a "Japan" factor and also to a "JPY" factor, your matrix $X$ looks like (for the case of 4 stocks)
$$
X = \left(
\begin{array}
&1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{array} 
\right)
$$
and the factor-mimicking portfolios are
$$
(X^TX)^+ X^T = \left(
\begin{array}
&.125 & .125 & .125 & .125\\
.125 & .125 & .125 & .125 \\
\end{array} 
\right)
$$
i.e the two factor-mimicking portfolios are identical, and each has a total weight of $0.5$. If instead you had a single factor i.e. just "Japan" or just "JPY" but not both, then the factor-mimicking portfolio would have a weight of 0.25 in each stock, with a total weight of 1.

thanks @Chris. One more follow up question on this. Should there be any restriction on the portfolio for which I am trying to attribute the performance? e.g. if I pick 3 stocks from Japan, 3 from China and 3 from Taiwan then the factor returns wont mean much and the attribution would yield some random numbers.
So Is it safe to say that portfolios with same country for all stocks (which represent the full market ) will be best for such task of pnl attribution using multi factor model?

Yes, that's safe to say.
